# Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-02-02` to be a date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have a html5 input date field,

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob" name="dob"/>
```

i want to send the date format to server in the following order,

```
2013-09-22
```

### controller

```
   $scope.personalDetailsObj = {
          "personalDetails": {
             "dob": new Date(2015, 2, 2)
       }
    }
    $scope.submitbtn = function(){
      $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob = $filter('date')($scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob,'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

But i am getting error saying: **Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-02-02` to be a date**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter will format date as string

```
$filter('date')($scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

And you are assign it to the model which input type is a date

```
$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob = $filter('date')($scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

If input type is date then ng-model should remain as date type

Comment: can u give me a solution? i want to send date string  'yyyy-mm-dd' to server

Comment: well assign it to another variable then send it to the server or copy model object into another then make change there then pass that object to the server. @vishnu